Rank probabilities for dependent data
It is well known that for iid sample $X_1, \dots, X_T$ rank probabilities are uniform over $1, \dots, T$. In other words, fixing $1 \le i_0 \le T$, probability of $X_{i_0}$ having rank $k$ (i.e., $X_{i_0} = X_{(k)}$) is $1/n$.
I am interested in such probabilities, but for the case of NOT iid random variables. Namely, let $\hat{z}_1, \dots, \hat{z}_T$ be estimated GARCH residuals (they are obviously non-iid). I want to bound $p_k = \mathcal{P}(\hat{z}_{i_0} = \hat{z}_{(k)})$:
I want to show that $|p_k - \frac{1}{T}| < \frac{1}{T}$.
I would be grateful for any literature/hints that could help to estimate rank probabilities for GARCH residuals.
UPD: I am thinking of representation of $\hat{z}_i = z_i + \Delta_i$, where $\Delta_i = o_p(1)$, may be this decomposition will lead to some useful bounds in the form of
$$\mathcal{P}(\hat{z}_{i_0} = \hat{z}_{(k)}) \le \mathcal{P}(z_{i_0} = z_{(k)}) + \mathcal{P}(\Delta_{i_0} = \Delta_{(k)}) = \frac{1}{T} + \varepsilon.$$
While this is NOT true bound, I was just thinking about something similar.

This question is framed too generally to have any useful answers.  Could you make it more specific?

Thanks for the comment @whuber. I modified the question so that it is more specific.
